# Audio stopped work on Rasbian Lite after reboot

Tags: pi-3, audio, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

So I know there's a lot of similar posts here, but I've read everything on the first 2 pages of Google and no luck yet.  There's only one command that does actually produce audio for me: `/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_audio/hello_audio.bin 1`.  Literally nothing else I try has produced audio.  I've set up bluetooth, spotify connect, and airplay.  Audio *was* working for a day or two but I tried it again and I couldn't get any audio.

I've tried everything on this site: https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Sound and nothing worked.

Help please?

Comment: Could you write down which Pi, which OS, what did you install, what did you try et cetera?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Check the situation out by `alsamixer` & `amixer`.

Comment: Yes sorry for not providing that sooner.  I have the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and the latest Raspbian Lite, 4.19.

As for what I've tried, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling all packages I thought would be relevant.  I have pulseaudio installed which I know sometimes causes issues, but even after purging it the issue remained.

Comment: Do you used `alsamixer` to boost loudness from 0 on the output interface?

Comment: Wow I feel like such an idiot...yup it somehow got set back to zero.  Ugh, thank you!